# How to split a string in python (extract the date : the date structure is different)

Tags: python, split

I have a list of file names with path like:

```
sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_Full_2018-02-04-000001.bak
sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_Full_2018-02-05.bak
sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_backup_2018_01_15_000000_9035698.bak
```

How can I split it, to get output as:

```
sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_Full and 2018-02-04-000001
sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_Full and 2018-02-05
sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_backup and 2018_01_15_000000_9035698
```

I tried this code:

```
name1= os.path.splitext(key.name)[0]
string = name1[-17:]
```

In this way, I can only get the date for the string like first one...

Comment: shouldn't the last one be `...dbname_backup` ?

Comment: What is the criteria of spliting? some character or before date in format YYYY-MM-DD? last string has different date format, is that right?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it should be dbname_backup. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @AndriiNikolaienko I just want to split this string into 2 parts. One part is  the string before date and and the other is date

Comment: strings in python have a `split` method, did you try that?

Comment: @PaulH At the very beginning, I thought the date time format is same, so I was trying  below query to get the date...then I notice not all the files have the same date format

name1= os.path.splitext(key.name)[0]
string = name1[-17:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:
import re

```
s = 'sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_backup_2018_01_15_000000_9035698.bak'
re.split("(\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2})", s);
```

Result will be

```
['sql/BODCPRODxxxx/dbname_Full_', '2018_02_04', '-000001.bak']
```

You need not to combine last and second to last parts for one string.

Comment: Good point! I was too focusing on dividing the string into two parts, never thought this way. Thank you!